# Update Visual Studio 2019 TypeScript version

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

Even though Visual Studio Installer says I have v3.7 installed:

[image: Visual Studio Installer view]

In the editor it says I still have the 1.8:

[image: Text editor view]

Do you know what the problem is and how I can change the version in use?